# Two subfigures beside each other using circuitikz

Tags: floats, subfloats, circuitikz

I have a problem that I can't resolve. I want two put two circuits near to each other and not on top of each other. Here is my code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering

\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}

\begin{circuitikz}
\draw   
(0,2) to [american controlled current source, l=$g_m V_{GS_1}$](0,0)
(2,2) to [R, l=$r_{o_1}$] (2,0)
(3.5,2) to [american controlled current source, l=$g_m V_{GS_2}$](3.5,0)
(5.5,2) to [R, l=$r_{o_2}$] (5.5,0)
(0,2) to [short, -o] (6,2)
(0,0) to [short, -o] (6,0);
\end{circuitikz}

\caption{with $r_o$}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}

\begin{circuitikz}
\draw   
(0,2) to [american controlled current source, l=$g_m V_{GS_1}$](0,0)
(3,2) to [american controlled current source, l=$g_m V_{GS_2}$](3,0)
(0,2) to [short, -o] (4,2)
(0,0) to [short, -o] (4,0);
\end{circuitikz}

\caption{with no $r_o$}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{DC small signal model}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: My Output]

Can someone help me to figure out how to put the two circuits beside each other and not on top of each other?

Comment: Hi, welcome. As is the case in normal text, an empty line in the code means a paragraph break, so your two subfigures are in different paragraphs. Hence, don't use an empty line there, as AndréC demonstrates in his answer.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425299/setting-the-subfigures-horizontally-in-pgfplots, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99600/how-do-i-get-the-two-circuits-to-display-side-by-side/99609?r=SearchResults&s=29|8.7584#99609, and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173344/image-orientation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this ?

[image]

Just delete the white line between the two `subfigure` environments and to space them, add a space with `\hspace`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
%\centering

\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}

\begin{circuitikz}
\draw   
(0,2) to [american controlled current source, l=$g_m V_{GS_1}$](0,0)
(2,2) to [R, l=$r_{o_1}$] (2,0)
(3.5,2) to [american controlled current source, l=$g_m V_{GS_2}$](3.5,0)
(5.5,2) to [R, l=$r_{o_2}$] (5.5,0)
(0,2) to [short, -o] (6,2)
(0,0) to [short, -o] (6,0);
\end{circuitikz}

\caption{with $r_o$}
\end{subfigure}\hspace{3cm}% <-- no space between subfigure 
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}

\begin{circuitikz}
\draw   
(0,2) to [american controlled current source, l=$g_m V_{GS_1}$](0,0)
(3,2) to [american controlled current source, l=$g_m V_{GS_2}$](3,0)
(0,2) to [short, -o] (4,2)
(0,0) to [short, -o] (4,0);
\end{circuitikz}

\caption{with no $r_o$}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{DC small signal model}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```